# Registering a parked domain after it expires

Tags: domains

I want to register a domain, but that domain is currently in use, parked. For the particular page, I queried *whois.net* and found out that the domain expires 2014-12-16.

How can I get the domain when it expires? When do I need to start placing the order for that domain? Can I simply do it with my preferred provider or should I contact *whois.net* directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will only be able to register the domain only if somebody does not renew it.

> A domain name is not available for re-registration as soon as it expires. Most registrars allow a grace period that can be as short as one or two weeks or as long as a year for registrants to renew expired domain names. [The actual grace period can be different for each individual registrar and domain name extension.]
>
> After the registrar's grace period, most domain names have a redemption period. This period can last from two weeks to 30 days, and, during this time, the current registrant can renew the domain name by paying a redemption fee along with the domain name's renewal fee.
>
> If the current registrant does not renew or redeem the domain name, it might be auctioned. When a domain name is released to a public auction, you can participate and possibly capture the domain name by placing a bid on it.
>
> If the domain name is not renewed, redeemed, or purchased through an auction, it is returned to its registry. The registry determines when the domain name is released again for registration. Once it's released, you can register the domain name.

Source: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/572/when-can-i-register-an-expired-domain-name

Comment: source link : http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/572/when-can-i-register-an-expired-domain-name

Answer (score 1):

You can also backorder domain: it will be automatically registered on your name when it became available.

From GoDaddy:

> Domain Backorders is a service that helps you attempt to acquire a
>   domain name when it becomes available for registration. It includes a
>   Domain Monitoring membership, a GoDaddy Auctions® membership, $10
>   toward your first auction bid, and one year of domain name
>   registration.

See also [Godaddy info](http://ca.godaddy.com/domainaddon/domain-backorders.aspx).